# How to set the REST api address in Angular according to build?

Tags: angular, webpack, jhipster

I have an Angular front-end project generated by JHipster(5.8.2) and would like to adjust the settings so that when the build was 'prod' the REST API address would be a value and when the build was 'dev' the address would be another, however I could not make this change in the webpack.dev.js, webpack.prod.js, and webpack.common.js files.

In the webpack.common.js file I set a value instead of empty string in SERVER_API_URL, however, this value was applied to all builds. I also tried using a method to set the value as it is taught on some sites, but it did not work either.

How can I make this setting in the webpack files that were generated by JHipster?

Here is the code for the three files:

webpack.common.js:

```js
const webpack = require('webpack');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const rxPaths = require('rxjs/_esm5/path-mapping');
const MergeJsonWebpackPlugin = require("merge-jsons-webpack-plugin");

const utils = require('./utils.js');

module.exports = (options) => ({
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.js'],
        modules: ['node_modules'],
        alias: {
            app: utils.root('src/main/webapp/app/'),
            ...rxPaths()
        }
    },
    stats: {
        children: false
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                loader: 'html-loader',
                options: {
                    minimize: true,
                    caseSensitive: true,
                    removeAttributeQuotes:false,
                    minifyJS:false,
                    minifyCSS:false
                },
                exclude: /(src\/main\/webapp\/index.html)/
            },
            {
                test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg|woff2?|ttf|eot)$/i,
                loader: 'file-loader',
                options: {
                    digest: 'hex',
                    hash: 'sha512',
                    name: 'content/[hash].[ext]'
                }
            },
            {
                test: /manifest.webapp$/,
                loader: 'file-loader',
                options: {
                    name: 'manifest.webapp'
                }
            },
            // Ignore warnings about System.import in Angular
            { test: /[\/\\]@angular[\/\\].+\.js$/, parser: { system: true } },
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env': {
                NODE_ENV: `'${options.env}'`,
                BUILD_TIMESTAMP: `'${new Date().getTime()}'`,
                VERSION: `'${utils.parseVersion()}'`,
                DEBUG_INFO_ENABLED: options.env === 'development',
                SERVER_API_URL: `''`
            }
        }),
        new CopyWebpackPlugin([
            { from: './node_modules/swagger-ui/dist/css', to: 'swagger-ui/dist/css' },
            { from: './node_modules/swagger-ui/dist/lib', to: 'swagger-ui/dist/lib' },
            { from: './node_modules/swagger-ui/dist/swagger-ui.min.js', to: 'swagger-ui/dist/swagger-ui.min.js' },
            { from: './src/main/webapp/swagger-ui/', to: 'swagger-ui' },
            { from: './src/main/webapp/content/', to: 'content' },
            { from: './src/main/webapp/favicon.ico', to: 'favicon.ico' },
            { from: './src/main/webapp/manifest.webapp', to: 'manifest.webapp' },
            // jhipster-needle-add-assets-to-webpack - JHipster will add/remove third-party resources in this array
            { from: './src/main/webapp/robots.txt', to: 'robots.txt' }
        ]),
        new MergeJsonWebpackPlugin({
            output: {
                groupBy: [
                    { pattern: "./src/main/webapp/i18n/pt-br/*.json", fileName: "./i18n/pt-br.json" },
                    { pattern: "./src/main/webapp/i18n/en/*.json", fileName: "./i18n/en.json" }
                    // jhipster-needle-i18n-language-webpack - JHipster will add/remove languages in this array
                ]
            }
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './src/main/webapp/index.html',
            chunks: ['vendors', 'polyfills', 'main', 'global'],
            chunksSortMode: 'manual',
            inject: 'body'
        })
    ]
});
```

webpack.prod.js:

```js
const webpack = require('webpack');
const webpackMerge = require('webpack-merge');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin = require("optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin");
const Visualizer = require('webpack-visualizer-plugin');
const MomentLocalesPlugin = require('moment-locales-webpack-plugin');
const TerserPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin');
const WorkboxPlugin = require('workbox-webpack-plugin');
const AngularCompilerPlugin = require('@ngtools/webpack').AngularCompilerPlugin;
const path = require('path');

const utils = require('./utils.js');
const commonConfig = require('./webpack.common.js');

const ENV = 'production';
const sass = require('sass');

module.exports = webpackMerge(commonConfig({ env: ENV }), {
    entry: {
        polyfills: './src/main/webapp/app/polyfills',
        global: './src/main/webapp/content/scss/global.scss',
        main: './src/main/webapp/app/app.main'
    },
    output: {
        path: utils.root('build/www'),
        filename: 'app/[name].[hash].bundle.js',
        chunkFilename: 'app/[id].[hash].chunk.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [{
            test: /(?:\.ngfactory\.js|\.ngstyle\.js|\.ts)$/,
            loader: '@ngtools/webpack'
        },
        {
            test: /\.scss$/,
            use: ['to-string-loader', 'css-loader', {
                loader: 'sass-loader',
                options: { implementation: sass }
            }],
            exclude: /(vendor\.scss|global\.scss)/
        },
        {
            test: /(vendor\.scss|global\.scss)/,
            use: [
                MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                'css-loader',
                'postcss-loader',
                {
                    loader: 'sass-loader',
                    options: { implementation: sass }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            test: /\.css$/,
            use: ['to-string-loader', 'css-loader'],
            exclude: /(vendor\.css|global\.css)/
        },
        {
            test: /(vendor\.css|global\.css)/,
            use: [
                MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                'css-loader',
                'postcss-loader'
            ]
        }]
    },
    optimization: {
        runtimeChunk: false,
        splitChunks: {
            cacheGroups: {
                commons: {
                    test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
                    name: 'vendors',
                    chunks: 'all'
                }
            }
        },
        minimizer: [
            new TerserPlugin({
                parallel: true,
                cache: true,
                terserOptions: {
                    ie8: false,
                    // sourceMap: true, // Enable source maps. Please note that this will slow down the build
                    compress: {
                        dead_code: true,
                        warnings: false,
                        properties: true,
                        drop_debugger: true,
                        conditionals: true,
                        booleans: true,
                        loops: true,
                        unused: true,
                        toplevel: true,
                        if_return: true,
                        inline: true,
                        join_vars: true
                    },
                    output: {
                        comments: false,
                        beautify: false,
                        indent_level: 2
                    }
                }
            }),
            new OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin({})
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            // Options similar to the same options in webpackOptions.output
            // both options are optional
            filename: '[name].[contenthash].css',
            chunkFilename: '[id].css'
        }),
        new MomentLocalesPlugin({
            localesToKeep: [
                    'pt-br',
                    'en'
                    // jhipster-needle-i18n-language-moment-webpack - JHipster will add/remove languages in this array
                ]
        }),
        new Visualizer({
            // Webpack statistics in target folder
            filename: '../stats.html'
        }),
        new AngularCompilerPlugin({
            mainPath: utils.root('src/main/webapp/app/app.main.ts'),
            tsConfigPath: utils.root('tsconfig-aot.json'),
            sourceMap: true
        }),
        new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
            minimize: true,
            debug: false
        }),
        new WorkboxPlugin.GenerateSW({
          clientsClaim: true,
          skipWaiting: true,
        })
    ],
    mode: 'production'
});
```

webpack.dev.js:

```js
const webpack = require('webpack');
const writeFilePlugin = require('write-file-webpack-plugin');
const webpackMerge = require('webpack-merge');
const BrowserSyncPlugin = require('browser-sync-webpack-plugin');
const ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin = require('fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin');
const FriendlyErrorsWebpackPlugin = require('friendly-errors-webpack-plugin');
const SimpleProgressWebpackPlugin = require('simple-progress-webpack-plugin');
const WebpackNotifierPlugin = require('webpack-notifier');
const path = require('path');
const sass = require('sass');

const utils = require('./utils.js');
const commonConfig = require('./webpack.common.js');

const ENV = 'development';

module.exports = (options) => webpackMerge(commonConfig({ env: ENV }), {
    devtool: 'eval-source-map',
    devServer: {
        contentBase: './build/www',
        proxy: [{
            context: [
                /* jhipster-needle-add-entity-to-webpack - JHipster will add entity api paths here */
                '/api',
                '/management',
                '/swagger-resources',
                '/v2/api-docs',
                '/h2-console',
                '/auth'
            ],
            target: `http${options.tls ? 's' : ''}://127.0.0.1:8080`,
            secure: false,
            changeOrigin: options.tls,
            headers: { host: 'localhost:9000' }
        }],
        stats: options.stats,
        watchOptions: {
            ignored: /node_modules/
        }
    },
    entry: {
        polyfills: './src/main/webapp/app/polyfills',
        global: './src/main/webapp/content/scss/global.scss',
        main: './src/main/webapp/app/app.main'
    },
    output: {
        path: utils.root('build/www'),
        filename: 'app/[name].bundle.js',
        chunkFilename: 'app/[id].chunk.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [{
            test: /\.ts$/,
            enforce: 'pre',
            loader: 'tslint-loader',
            exclude: [/(node_modules)/, new RegExp('reflect-metadata\\' + path.sep + 'Reflect\\.ts')]
        },
        {
            test: /\.ts$/,
            use: [
                'angular2-template-loader',
                {
                    loader: 'cache-loader',
                    options: {
                      cacheDirectory: path.resolve('build/cache-loader')
                    }
                },
                {
                    loader: 'thread-loader',
                    options: {
                        // there should be 1 cpu for the fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin
                        workers: require('os').cpus().length - 1
                    }
                },
                {
                    loader: 'ts-loader',
                    options: {
                        transpileOnly: true,
                        happyPackMode: true
                    }
                },
                'angular-router-loader'
            ],
            exclude: /(node_modules)/
        },
        {
            test: /\.scss$/,
            use: ['to-string-loader', 'css-loader', {
                loader: 'sass-loader',
                options: { implementation: sass }
            }],
            exclude: /(vendor\.scss|global\.scss)/
        },
        {
            test: /(vendor\.scss|global\.scss)/,
            use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'postcss-loader', {
                loader: 'sass-loader',
                options: { implementation: sass }
            }]
        },
        {
            test: /\.css$/,
            use: ['to-string-loader', 'css-loader'],
            exclude: /(vendor\.css|global\.css)/
        },
        {
            test: /(vendor\.css|global\.css)/,
            use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
        }]
    },
    stats: process.env.JHI_DISABLE_WEBPACK_LOGS ? 'none' : options.stats,
    plugins: [
        process.env.JHI_DISABLE_WEBPACK_LOGS
            ? null
            : new SimpleProgressWebpackPlugin({
                format: options.stats === 'minimal' ? 'compact' : 'expanded'
              }),
        new FriendlyErrorsWebpackPlugin(),
        new ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin(),
        new BrowserSyncPlugin({
            host: 'localhost',
            port: 9000,
            proxy: {
                target: 'http://localhost:9060'
            },
            socket: {
                clients: {
                    heartbeatTimeout: 60000
                }
            }
        }, {
            reload: false
        }),
        new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
            /angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/)/,
            path.resolve(__dirname, './src/main/webapp')
        ),
        new writeFilePlugin(),
        new webpack.WatchIgnorePlugin([
            utils.root('src/test'),
        ]),
        new WebpackNotifierPlugin({
            title: 'JHipster',
            contentImage: path.join(__dirname, 'logo-jhipster.png')
        })
    ].filter(Boolean),
    mode: 'development'
});
```

Comment: ave you tried using `process.env` to get the profile?

Comment: In the file common.js > plugins > `new webpack.DefinePlugin`, I set a ternary operator by this way: `SERVER_API_URL: options.env === 'development' ? developmentHost : productionHost`. But I not idea if this is the best way to resolve!